# initializing vectors with variables, C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I'd like to be able to initialize vectors using variables like this:

```
    int min,max;
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max); 
    vector<int> day(min, max, max);
```

But when I try I get an error message saying:

IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int, int, int)

Is there any way to get around this problem? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: If C++11 is available for you, you can use list-initialization like it `vector<int> day {min, max, max};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need list-initialisation to specify the vector's contents, assuming your compiler supports it:

```
vector<int> day{min, max, max};
```

Before C++11, it was rather more tedious:

```
vector<int> day;
day.push_back(min);
day.push_back(max);
day.push_back(max);
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm surprised they didn't use `operator<<` for that...

Comment: Prior to C++11 one could use boost::assign: `vector<int> day = boost::assign::list_of(min)(max)(max);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
int min,max;
scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);
int temp[] = {min, max, max};
vector<int> day(temp, temp + sizeof(temp) / sizeof(int));
```

It will cost you a little extra memory. Both `C++98` and `C++11` support this.

Comment: I would prefer `vector<int> day(begin(temp), end(temp));` instead -- it's a bit cleaner than doing pointer arithmetic inline.